# Active Directory `thumbnailPhoto` and `jpegPhoto`

Tags: c#, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, user-profile

I need to write via C# the user profile pictures into the Active Directory. First I tried using the `DirectoryServices` setting the two properties `thumbnailPhoto` and `jpegPhoto` to the `DirectoryEntry` object.
Because on some users I got `Access Denied` I tried using `Microsoft Graph SDK API` as followings:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    await _client.Users[user.Id].Photo.Content.PutAsync(stream);
}
```

where the loaded stream is byte[1743117].

Using this approach it works fine, but getting the image as following, returns a reduced version, 100x100, in other words, the thumbnail:

`await _client.Users[user.Email].Photo.Content.GetAsync()`

Then I noticed that pics are automatically synched to SharePoint Online, Exchange, but not to Teams, so I am wondering how all the magic works behind the curtains.

Furthermore, if I query the Active Dirctory again as followings:

```
using (DirectorySearcher dsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher())
{
    dsSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user) (mail=aMail))";
    SearchResult? result = dsSearcher.FindOne();

    if (result != null)
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry(result.Path))
        {
            user.Properties["jpegPhoto"];
            user.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"];
        }
    }
}
```

`jpegPhoto` is byte[507251] and `thumbnailPhoto` is byte[4994]

In the end what I need is:

- To write the images into AD, or somewhere the images are automatically sent to SharePoint Online, Exchange, Teams and all MS products.
- Somehow get these images from AD in their original form or at lease in a decent quality.

Comment: Graph is probably resizing it for you. The `thumbnailPhoto` attribute has a size limit of 100KB, but I think `jpegPhoto` is unlimited. Is the original image not square? Maybe it's just squaring it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Gabriel Luci, Ms Graph resizes the picture.

The problem accessing the active directory properties was due to permissions. In fact, the permissions `write all properties` is required.